# ILogger<> doesn't cause NLog to log in File

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nlog

I'm using NLog and I'm trying to log events using ILogger<> from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging qssembly.
According to the documentations everything is all correct e.g nlog.config and Ilogger injection etc. but ILogger's methods don't work at all.

These are some pieces of code which works and I can see the result in file:

```
using NLog;
Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("foo");
logger.Info("Program started");
```

But I'm trying this(which doesn't work):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
  public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
  {
      _logger = logger;
  }

  public async Task<User> Create()
  {
      _logger.LogInformation("Create Method's called");
  }
}
```

This is **nlog.config** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  internalLogLevel="info"
  internalLogFile="C:\temp\internal-nlog.log">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="File" 
            name="LogFile" 
            fileName="${basedir}\temp\nlog-${shortdate}.log" 
            layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${message} |     ${exception:format=tostring} | ${logger} | url: ${aspnet-request-url} |     action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="LogFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

This is inside of **Program.cs**:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logger loggerN = LogManager.GetLogger("foo");
        loggerN.Info("Program started");

        var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init Main");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e, "Program Shuted down");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseNLog()
            .ConfigureLogging(options => { options.ClearProviders(); })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

here just two first lines of **Main** works.

Comment: Are you calling `UseNLog()` in your `Program.cs`?

Comment: Can you show how you're registering NLog with the logging extensions?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error? Put a breakpoint at `_logger = logger` and see the value of `logger`. Go ahead and log something right after that line and see if it works there.

Comment: There is an asp.net core 2 example project with logging to file here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/tree/master/examples/ASP.NET%20Core%202/Visual%20Studio%202017/ASP.NET%20Core%202%20-%20VS2017

Comment: Yes, I'm Calling **UseNLog()**

Comment: I've added some pieces of code. Any Help?

Comment: Everything is OK because I can see the result when I call NLog.LogManager. And I have no error in Nlog log file

Comment: I think `.ConfigureLogging(options => { options.ClearProviders(); })` cause this problem. but I don't know WHY?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `UseNLog()` to be after `ConfigureLogging(options => { options.ClearProviders(); })`. For example:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(options => { options.ClearProviders(); })
        .UseNLog();
```

If you call `options.ClearProviders()` after `UseNLog()`, it causes NLog to be removed as a logging provider.

Comment: Yes one should read and follow the wiki-guide: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs